# Native Application in Tizen IDE: signing crashes and prints odd non-ASCII characters

Tags: c++, mingw, tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-sdk

When i execute web application is OK..
but when i execute native application is something wrong..
there are error message..

When i execute like ( Project right click -> Build Package -> TPK )

It occur the error message `Fail to build package`

here is Console

```
Start...
Command: C:\tizen-sdk\tools\smart-build-interface\bin\sbi.exe action tizen-emulator-2.2.native_llvm31.i386.cpp.app -- buildpackage -BUILD_DIR="C:/Users/Smilelcys/workspace/Sample/Debug" -ARCH=i386 -PKG_TYPE=TPK -PKG_NAME=oCHuYywejH -PRJ_NAME=Sample -ARTIFACT_NAME=Sample -PKG_VER=1.0.0 -SIGN_CERT_DIR="C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\developer\tizen-developer-ca.cer" -SIGN_AUTHOR_KEY="C:\tizen-sdk-data\keystore\author\kys.p12" -SIGN_AUTHOR_PWD="1234" -SIGN_DIST1_KEY="C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\distributor\tizen-distributor-signer.p12" -SIGN_DIST1_PWD="tizenpkcs12passfordsigner" -SIGN_DIST1_CA="C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\distributor\tizen-distributor-ca.cer" -SIGN_DIST2_KEY="" -SIGN_DIST2_PWD="" -SIGN_DIST2_CA="" -SIGN_DIST2_ROOT=""
Working Directory: C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample
Copying files...
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/rm -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/mkdir -p "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/shared"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/rm -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/oCHuYywejH-1.0.0-i386.tpk"
Warning: The file does not exist! C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/oCHuYywejH-1.0.0-i386.tpk
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/rm -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/oCHuYywejH-1.0.0-i386-debug.zip"
Warning: The file does not exist! C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/oCHuYywejH-1.0.0-i386-debug.zip
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/cp -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/../data" "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/data"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/cp -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/../shared/res" "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/shared/res"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/cp -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/../shared/data" "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/shared/data"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/cp -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/../shared/trusted" "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/shared/trusted"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/cp -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/../lib" "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/lib"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/cp -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/../res" "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/res"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/mkdir -p "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/setting"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/mkdir -p "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/bin"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/cp -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/Sample.exe" "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/bin/Sample.exe"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/mkdir -p "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/info"
C:/tizen-sdk/ide/..//tools/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/cp -rf "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/../manifest.xml" "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug/.tpk/info/manifest.xml"
Signing...
C: && cd C:\tizen-sdk\tools\smart-build-interface\..\ide\bin && cmd.exe /C native-signing.bat "C:\Users\Smilelcys\workspace\Sample\Debug\.tpk" "C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\developer\tizen-developer-ca.cer" "C:\tizen-sdk-data\keystore\author\kys.p12" "****" "C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\distributor\tizen-distributor-signer.p12" "****" "C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\distributor\tizen-distributor-ca.cer" "" "****" "" ""
'java' ( ) Ǵ ܺ , ִ α׷ , Ǵ
ġ ƴմϴ .
Signing failed!
```

Comment: BTW. I've changed the title of your question. Now it should attract more attention. Please try to focus not on requests, but on facts, problems and observations. Hearing about "odd characters" in the log file is more important that "I need your support". You see, if you hadn't need support, you'd not write here, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

It certainly fails at the 'Signing" step. I don't know the Tizen toosuite, but the last parameters that are passed to the `native-signing.bat` are "empty". It looks strange and may be the cause of problem, but also can be perfectly OK. You should check if they are configured properly, just in case.

But more worrying is the next part, with `'java' ( )` and the trash that follows. It seems like misconfigured input/output (ie. the `native-signing.bat` calls something and outputs to the STDOUT instead of a binary file), or, worse, like some really ugly crash and printing trash instead of messages.

I'd definitely check the `native-signing.bat` file to see if it is damaged, and asking on the Tizen forums or tech support. It looks quite bad. It may end up in reinstalling the SDK and/or IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Tizen SDK -> Security Profiles` . Delete the existing profile and generate a new profile and try again to build. If problem persists, delete the debug folder and try again